# Change the color of random letters in a paragraph

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, each

I want to change color of some random characters in a paragraph to red on a button click. Please find my code. I am having some errors in this.

```
$('input').click(function(){

   var para = $('#para');
   var position = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
   var character = [];

   var i=0
   while ( i <= 30 )
   {
      character[i] = para.html().substr(position*(i+1), 1);
      i++;
   }

   $.each(character, function() {
     character.css('color','red');
   });

});
```

First of all I created an array which would contain 30 random letters from a paragraph
Next I used `each()` to iterate over each of the elements in the array to apply the css property.
But an error pops up in the console window saying object has no method 'css'

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You can call css method for jquery objects only. For your case, your array elements are just string.

Comment: i did ... but that too does not help

Comment: Well, your `$.each` logic doesn't make sense. `character` is an array and you cannot use jQuery methods on it. You need to create elements for all of your characters, change their  colors and append them to the page.

Comment: could you please elaborate .

Comment: what is `para` a input or a element like div/p

Comment: @anubhavgupta `character` is an array. You're treating it as a jQuery object by doing `character.css(...)`. Hint: the elements of the array are passed to you as the arguments to the callback. See the documentation on `$.each`.

Comment: its a div with id 'para'.. when i click the checkbox input on the page, the css change is supposed to occur

Comment: $.each can be applied only to jQuery objects, so what are jQuery objects, they are those objects which you get after successful execution of a jQuery query string, eg $("#para"). IF you want to apply different colors to each letter in para you may have to put each chara in different tags eg div or span like <span>A</span> <span>B</span>

Comment: @sij not true. `$(...).each` is designed to be used over jQuery objects only, `$.each` can iterate over (pseudo-)arrays and plain objects equally well.

Comment: the purpose of this is to select random letters from the para everytime the chckbox is clicked and change its color

Comment: @Jan you are correct let me edit my resp

Comment: http://letteringjs.com/

Comment: even with lettering.js you need to have every chara in different tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, CSS method will work only on jquery objects. You have strings in character array. css method won't work on strings.

Secondly, Your each method is written wrong. It should be like this

```
$.each(character, function(index, value) {
    // Do something
});
```

For your problem statement, to change color of some random characters in your string. Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/XdRRG/1/). Try this out.

Here is code:

```
$('input').click(function(){

var para = $('#para');
var charArray = $('span', para);

// case: No span (Initial String)
if (charArray.length === 0) {
    var html = para.html();
    var newArr = [];
    var len = html.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        newArr.push('<span>' + html[i] + '</span>');
    }
    html = newArr.join('');
    para.html(html);
    charArray = $('span', para);
}

// Reset all spans
$.each(charArray, function(i, value) {
    value.style.color = '';
});

var paralen = charArray.length;

for (var i=0; i<30; i++) {
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    pos = pos % paralen;
    charArray[pos].style.color = 'red';
}

});
```

Comment: @anubhav You do realize that overwriting the html contents is the same as emptying the element and appending the new characters right...

Comment: yes i do . but in your answer all other characters except the changed ones vanished. all characters are supposed to be retained

Comment: @anubhavgupta Please find updated code and updated fiddle link. Earlier code was not working for all cases.

Comment: it's fantastic that this was put together, but I am wondering instead of setting the style color to red, how would one just add a class to the selected letters, and then remove that class to all the others letters? .addClass()/.removeClass() doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: @Murphy1976 This is a good idea. you can do it as well. Inside the for loop of 30, you can just say `$(charArray[pos]).addClass('red')` where `red` class will contain the css properties. I agree +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to review the documentation for [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each). A possible solution:

```
$('input').click(function() {

    var $para = $('#para');
    var position = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    var character = [];

    for ( var i=0; i <= 30; i++ ) {
        character[i] = $("<span>" + $para.text().substr(position*(i+1), 1) 
                                  + "</span>");
        character[i].css('color', 'red');
    }

    $para.empty();

    $.each(character, function(idx, val) {
        $(val).appendTo($para);
    });
});
```

Comment: this is what i wanted . But instead of emptying the para div and appending the new letters , i need it to dynamically change the colors in the para itself.

Comment: You can't call a jQuery method on a character. It has to be on a jQuery object. Which has to be wrapped around an HTML element. `<span>` elements are inline, so they should do what you want visually. What is the issue when you run this?

Comment: there is no issue . but the ultimate goal is to leave the para as it is ($para.empty() is obsolete) and just changing the color of the targeted letters wherever in para they are present. you are emptying the para and then appending it, which is not required

Comment: You can't target letters with CSS styles. Modifying the DOM nodes is neccessary. Deleting everything and starting anew is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @anubhav It *is* required. That's the point. See Jan Dvorak's comment above

Comment: thank you for bonus knowledge jan and nbrooks. but i was trying to achieve what blunderboy showed up there. thanks again :)

Comment: @anubhav It's the same thing...he's overwriting the elements with the modified HTML content. But you're welcome :)