# How to select a random letter from a link in a <li> and color it on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress theme for a client and my designer thought it would be fun to color only one letter of the menu items on hover. I tried to get this working with lettering.js(http://letteringjs.com/), but that way I'd have to specify exactly which letter I want to color in CSS and my CSS quickly became a mess of nth-child selectors and whatnot.

I'd like to use jQuery in a way that selects a random letter (just one random letter, not multiple) from a link within a list item and colours it to a specified, on hover. I've found this: [Change the color of random letters in a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432075/change-the-color-of-random-letters-in-a-paragraph) and tried to edit it to work for my case, but I couldn't get it to work.

Can anyone come up with a solution?

Comment: I guess you could pass the string in and then generate a random number up to `string.length` and use that as an index to pass `span` tags around that point with a specific class that has a hover style? A bit convoluted though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any string as a character array; you can access it by index `"abc"[0]` or `slice` it, for instance.

So given a random index, `index` you might be able to divide it into

```
text.slice(0, index) // part before target character
+ text[index] // target character
+ text.slice(index+1) // part after target character
```

A complete solution, then, might look like this:

```
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
    var index = getRandom(text.length);

    $(this).html(
        [text.slice(0, index), '<span class="colored">', text[index], '</span>', text.slice(index+1)].join('')
    );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hzefs/). Reload to re-randomize.

Note that this doesn't cover for things such as the randomized character being whitespace. A simple solution to that might be to throw in something like

```
while(text[index] == ' ') index = getRandom(text.length);
```

Comment: Nice use of an array and join - makes the code look very friendly.

Comment: That works fine, I just had to wrap `$('li').markRandomLetter();` in `$(document).ready();` and all was good. I assume I throw in the `while` loop after the variable declaration right?